# Highlight a substring within a string based on starting and ending positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given a String as input. Assume *"the leading blade edges of the fan blade is bulged"*.
Clicking on a button will pass the string to the server and the server returns a JSON object

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "name": "blade",
      "startPos": 12,
      "endPos": 17

    },
    {
      "name": "bulged",
      "startPos": 44,
      "endPos": 50 
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I have to highlight the two words 'blade' and 'bulged' in the input string and display them as output.

*Input:*"the leading blade edges of the fan blade is bulged"

*Expected Output:* the leading **blade** edges of the fan blade is **bulged**

I can always match the words and highlight them using Regex, but it will highlight both occurances of 'blade' in the input string.

Is there any way in JavaScript to identify the string based on position and highlight them.

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Here us my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2mx5Ldq/)

Comment: Regex by default will look for the first instance of a match only. You need to remove the `g` from your pattern which makes it  a global search.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Hi.. It need not necessarily be the first instance. There could be a possibility of three instances and the word to be highlighted could be the second one

Comment: What logic would determine the instance to be highlighted?

Comment: The starting and ending position of the string to be highlighted will be available.

Comment: Where are you expecting the output? do you want to see the result as a text of another tag?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Probably `"startPos": 12`, right? @VSri58 Why not `substring(a, b)`?

Comment: @VenkataPanga  The output could be displayed in a label or a div, which I forgot to include in my Fiddle.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp this is what you need! but beware, the substr expects a start pos and a length parameter - so change your server sided script to return the length instead of the endpos.

Comment: @errand `substring(a, b)` takes start (a) and end (b) as input, though.

Comment: @Oskar: haven't seen this one ;) and couldn't imagine, that there are two functions, just to cover two approaches^^

Comment: @errand : Thanks for your suggestion. But I was expecting a solution based on my current JSON format with starting and ending pos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JS string method [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to find the relevant sections of the string. In this case, since you have to add markup for the highlighting, you want to find the substrings before and after your target word.

Then add the highlighting as appropriate, using `<strong>` or something similar. See example below.

You need to loop over `obj.result`, while accounting for the fact that adding markup like `<strong>` changes the starting indices of later words. You might consider highlighting starting with words near the end of the string, to avoid complexity with the indices. To do this, sort the list in descending order by `startPos`, as shown below.

```js
var str = "the leading blade edges of the fan blade is bulged";
var obj = {
  "result": [{
    "name": "blade",
    "startPos": 12,
    "endPos": 17

  }, {
    "name": "bulged",
    "startPos": 44,
    "endPos": 50
  }]
};
obj.result.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.startPos - a.startPos;
})

for (var i = 0; i < obj.result.length; i++) {
  var start = obj.result[i].startPos,
    end = obj.result[i].endPos,
    before = str.substring(0, start),
    after = str.substring(end),
    middle = "<strong>" + obj.result[i].name + "</strong>";

  str = before + middle + after;
}


document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what you are looking for is probably a more structural method, but i guess the best shot would be something as below:

```
var str = "the leading blade edges of the fan blade is bulged";
for(var loc in obj.result){
    str = str.substring(0,obj.result[loc].startPos+loc*17) + "<strong>" +
      str.substring(obj.result[loc].startPos+loc*17,obj.result[loc].endPos+loc*17) + "</strong>" +
      str.substring(obj.result[loc].endPos+loc*17);
}
```

Comment: This is a reasonable approach, but it doesn't quite work. Since you change the value of `str` in your loop (by adding `"<strong>"` etc.), the `startPos` from the server is no longer correct in the modified string. I'm doing something similar to this in my answer, if you're interested in seeing how I accounted for that.

Comment: You are right, i missed that point. But you can keep a counter adressing how many characters are added to the string so far.

I edited code accordingly.